# Partitioned table on synapse

Tags: partition, azure-synapse

I'm trying to create a new partitioned table on my SqlDW (synapse) based on a partitioned table on Spark (synapse) with

```
%%spark
val df1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM sparkTable")
df1.write.partitionBy("year").sqlanalytics("My_SQL_Pool.dbo.StudentFromSpak", Constants.INTERNAL )
```

> Error : StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
> StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
> StructuredStream-spark package version: 2.4.5-1.3.1
> java.sql.SQLException:
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: External file access
> failed due to internal error: 'File
> /synapse/workspaces/test-partition-workspace/sparkpools/myspark/sparkpoolinstances/c5e00068-022d-478f-b4b8-843900bd656b/livysessions/2021/03/09/1/tempdata/SQLAnalyticsConnectorStaging/application_1615298536360_0001/aDtD9ywSeuk_shiw47zntKz.tbl/year=2000/part-00004-5c3e4b1a-a580-4c7e-8381-00d92b0d32ea.c000.snappy.parquet:
> HdfsBridge::CreateRecordReader - **Unexpected error encountered
> creating the record reader: HadoopExecutionException: Column count
> mismatch. Source file has 5 columns, external table definition has 6
> columns.'**   at
> com.microsoft.spark.sqlanalytics.utils.SQLAnalyticsJDBCWrapper.executeUpdateStatement(SQLAnalyticsJDBCWrapper.scala:89)
> at

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlanalytics()` function name has been changed to `synapsesql()`.  It does not currently support writing partitioned tables but you could implement this yourself, eg by writing multiple tables back to the dedicated SQL pool and the using partition switching back there.

The syntax is simply (as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export)):

```
df.write.synapsesql("<DBName>.<Schema>.<TableName>", <TableType>)
```

An example would be:

```
df.write.synapsesql("yourDb.dbo.yourTablePartition1", Constants.INTERNAL)
df.write.synapsesql("yourDb.dbo.yourTablePartition2", Constants.INTERNAL)
```

Now do the partition switching in the database using the `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH PARTITION` syntax.